# Laravel middleware for subscription

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am trying to write middleware in Laravel 5 that will check if a user has a subscription, and it isn't canceled. If it doesn't exist or is canceled, then they will be locked into one page (billing). Problem is, I end up in a redirect loop. I understand why, but I just can't figure out what the correct thing to do is. Thanks in advance

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{


    if (\Auth::check()) 
    {
        // if subscription does not exist
        if (\Auth::user()->hospital->subscription == null || \Auth::user()->hospital->subscription !== 'Active') {
           return redirect('billing');
        }

    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Hi. "billing" is what? it is in your route right.
Can you try something like this, return Redirect::route('billing');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, I end up in a redirect loop.

Looks like you are applying the middleware in the whole application including the billing page. So, you need to specify where the middleware class should be considered, this can be achieved at `/app/Http/kernel.php`.

Also, you can considere make an additional validation at your middleware clas like:

```
// billing (http://example.com/billing)
$path = $request->path();

if ($path !== 'billing')
{

    if (\Auth::check()) 
    {
        // if subscription does not exist
        if (\Auth::user()->hospital->subscription == null || \Auth::user()->hospital->subscription !== 'Active') {
           return redirect('billing');
        }

    }
}
return $next($request);
```

Comment: That did the trick for getting me out the redirect loop. I do have it in the whole app, but now I can see it to be a problem this way. Even though I am now locked to the billing page, it will run the subscription check even when I enter payment information, which will cause it to keep coming back to the billing page. Not sure what the best approach for this would be.

Comment: The best approach is to edit the kernel file. Why? because you can specify in which url/routes the middleware class should be applied. The expression `if ($path !== 'billing')` is just a fix but not a recommended solution. Please, read a little bit about middleware classes in laravel's docs, it has a nice explanation on how to play with them. Finally, if you need help we are are glad to give you a hand

Comment: I ended up setting up a route group for the middleware to be applied to so that it isn't being applied to the whole app. Thanks for the help. Very much appreciated.